# /bin/bash: redraw: command not found

Tags: bash, vim, i3

On saving my .i3 config file, I get the following message at the bottom:
`"~/.i3" 234L, 8266C written/bin/bash: redraw: command not found`

The file does appear to save. However, I think the vim screen doesn't get redrawn, which is possibly related to the error.

Comment: Likely wrong PATH. Also the error message looks weird, as if there were somewhere a carriage return in the output.

Comment: how would I check the PATH?

Comment: ???  Right before you are calling `redraw` in your script, you simply do put a `echo $PATH` there....

Comment: I don't have a script that calls a "redraw". I don't even have the word 'redraw' anywhere in the i3 config file.

Comment: So, where do you call it? You aren't by chance invoking some external tool from within vim? Did you check your vim macros?

Comment: this error message is only being displayed when editing the .i3 config file, not when editing any other file in vim

Comment: That's why I suspect that vim macros, which implicitly shell out to something, are executed. A macro could query the filename and do something particular for it. Did you check your `.vimrc`?

Comment: If the behaviour is vim-specific (did you try other editors, such as nvim or a completely different one, such as emacs or nano?), I suggest that you post your question on [superuser](https://superuser.com/), and emphasize in your question, that the error does not occur when you save a different file.

Comment: yes, you were right. in my vimrc I have the following line: `autocmd BufWritePost ~/.i3 silent !i3-msg reload | redraw`. I think it's supposed to reload the i3 session whenever I save the config file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227962/discussion-between-zmunk-and-user1934428).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had the following line in my .vimrc file which is supposed to reload the i3 session whenever the .i3 config file is saved.

```
autocmd BufWritePost ~/.i3 silent !i3-msg reload | redraw
```

When I change that line as follows, it seems to work now.

```
autocmd BufWritePost ~/.i3 execute '!i3-msg reload' | redraw!
```

I also had to add a line `autocmd!` at the top of my .vimrc to clear all previous autocmds.

The explanation for exclamation point at the end of the `redraw` command (from the [vim docs](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/gnu/vim/various.html)):

> :redr[aw][!]      Redraw the screen right now. When ! is included it is
> cleared first.